# Android Studio - "layout_constraintTop_toEndOf not found."

Tags: xml, android-studio, gradle, wysiwyg

After rearranging my layout using the WYSIWYG editor, there is a problem. I set some new constraints on existing TextViews and found I could no longer compile.

Java compiler says `failed linking file resources` and the issue is `layout_constraintTop_toEndOf' not found.`.

My layout is a ConstraintLayout and my Grade file has the line `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'`.

I tried `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, `Build -> Clean Project`, and `Invalidate Caches / Restart` with no success.

I really don't know what to say on this one; I can't run the code if I remove the constraint (I get a warning that the element needs a constraint), yet I can't run the code with the constraint set.

A Google search yields nothing of use, it seems I may have to reinstall and go from there, unless someone else has run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint that you are trying to use, `layout_constraintTop_toEndOf` is not valid. For a list of constraints that you can choose from, see this link (look at Figure 2):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout